# Dash input from callback and string

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I would like to get a table returned based on both a dash `Input` and some other 'string' value. The idea is to re-use the same callback at multiple places, based on the same `Input` but differing the `string` value. Right now, my callback is something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    [
     Output('table', 'data'),
     Output('table', 'columns')],
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_output(selected_type):
#(code continues)

## referred in app as:
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Some dynamic table")
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=['X','Y'],
        value='X'
    ),
    dash_table.DataTable(id='table') # arguments to update_output() based only on Input dropdown
])
```

I would like to have it adapted such that the `dropdown` input remains, but I can specify a string on the arguments of the function. Something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    [
     Output('table', 'data'),
     Output('table', 'columns')],
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_output(selected_type, some_string='dog'):
#(code continues)

## referred in app as:
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Some dynamic table")
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=['X','Y'],
        value='X'
    ),
    '''This is table with dog:''' 
    dash_table.DataTable(id='table', 'dog') # arguments to update_output() based on Input dropdown, and I specify the string "dog" here myself
    '''This is table with cat:''' 
    dash_table.DataTable(id='table', 'cat') # arguments to update_output() based on Input dropdown, and I specify the string "cat" here myself
])
```

Perhaps I'm making it more complex than it needs to be? The end goal is that a table should be returned based on both user `Input` and my specification. Of course, an easy workaround is to have a single callback for each of my own arguments (e.g. `update_output_cat()` and `update_output_dog()`) but this is not really a good solution

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use the keywords "State" and for example set a text input with the default value "dog".

Here is an example with your code :

```py
@app.callback(
    [
     Output('table', 'data'),
     Output('table', 'columns')],
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')].
    State('table-name', 'value')
)
def update_output(selected_type, some_string):
#(code continues)

## referred in app as:
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Some dynamic table")
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=['X','Y'],
        value='X'
    ),
    dcc.Input(id="table-name", type="text", placeholder="", value="dog"),
    '''This is table with dog:''' 
    dash_table.DataTable(id='table', 'dog') # arguments to update_output() based on Input dropdown, and I specify the string "dog" here myself
    '''This is table with cat:''' 
    dash_table.DataTable(id='table', 'cat') # arguments to update_output() based on Input dropdown, and I specify the string "cat" here myself
])
```